# Sending variables to a Cloud Page using a push notification

Tags: marketing-cloud, cloudpage, mobilepush

I'm trying to use push with AppInbox/Cloud Pages. I want the Cloud Page that is linked to the push message to be able to display dynamic content based on an attribute for that contact. This page - https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_rn_april_2019_mp_jb_entry_source_personalization.htm&type=5 - says that it is possible to personalise Cloud Page content but doesn't say how.

I've already had a Salesforce support case opened and closed with no luck - apparently it's not their job to assist me with how to do something even if they say something is possible but back it up with no documentation for how it might be done.

I've tried the normal way you'd do it from an email, using both the _subscriberkey personalisation string as well as the RequestParameter function with fields from the entry source DE, but neither of these work.

Given you're selecting a static Cloud Page when you set up the send and there's no visible way to add attributes, how do you actually get a Cloud Page to pick up these values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pick up journey entry source parameters on a Cloud Page using the AttributeValue function. As an example, my journey entry source contained 3 fields - SubscriberKey, Tier and FirstName. The code below displayed all these values on my linked AppInbox page.

```
%%[
  SET @cKey = AttributeValue("SubscriberKey")
  SET @tier = AttributeValue("Tier")
  SET @firstName = AttributeValue("FirstName")
]%
Contact Key: %%=v(@cKey)=%%<br />
Tier: %%=v(@tier)=%%<br />
First Name: %%=v(@firstName)=%%%
```

Comment: Very nice Jarrett.