# Send a personalized information through a Cloud Page using an Inbox PUSH

Tags: marketing-cloud, cloudpage, mobilepush, inbox

I would like to send personalized fields from a Data Extension  through a Cloud Page using an Inbox PUSH.
When a client open the message in the Inbox section from the APP , I would like to show for example the name from each client. The idea is to show personalized data from the client and be able to keep for a period this info in their inbox .

This is the simple code I am using , but the name is not showing up . Is something missing? Is it possible right now in Marketing Cloud ? Any help is appreciated.

```ampscript
%%[
var @sk, @Name
set @sk = RequestParameter("data_extension")
set @Name = Lookup("data_extension","Nombre","Id_Cliente", @sk)
]%%
Your name is : %%=v(@Name)=%%
```

Comment: Where do you want this data to appear?  Is it part of the page, the message title, the inbox subject?

Comment: I asked much the same question a couple of weeks ago and worked out the answer...see https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/344677/sending-variables-to-a-cloud-page-using-a-push-notification/344719

Comment: Hi Bill, I would like to see the data in the Inbox section in the APP. It is part of the page, no any title o subject. If a preview the cloud page what I see is :  Your name is         .  Anything is showing taking into account the subscriberkey.

Comment: Hi Jarrett thanks for the answer, but I would like to personalized from a Data Extension, not using attribute values. The same idea we do in an email, that based on data from a data extension we give the opportunity to show to each client their own personal information.

Comment: @JarrettBush regarding the code you used in a Journey, what was your entry source? Then you sent a Push and in your inbox you were able to see the the contactket, firstname and tier? THanks

Comment: The entry source is the data extension. So if you send your push message in a journey you can pick up the data extension values using the AttributeValue function in the AppInbox Cloud Page.

Comment: Hi @JarrettBush, many thanks for your help. We were able to perform this send from the Journey as you suggested . Really appreciated your comments , because now we can personalized Push Inbox messages and a new 'world' is opened.

Comment: No problem at all. Glad I could help and it worked for you :)